# Should we say "In Telegram" or "On Telegram"?

Tags: prepositions

When we are talking about the pieces of software or messengers, what preposition should we use, **on** or **in**?

For example:

> If you have any questions, feel free to drop me a line **on / in**
> Telegram.

Should we use **on**, **in**, or both of them are acceptable? And if both of them are acceptable indeed, is there a difference in meaning between the two?

Answer (score -1):

If it's a software platform such as WhatsApp or Twitter you would usually say: on, by, or via.

If its a type of messaging (telegram, telephone, mail) you would usually say by or via.